# How to show the last and newest modified post in a custom category?

Tags: pre-get-posts

I build a plugin with `pre_get_posts()`, which calls my oldest modified post.

But I want to see the newest modified after this posts too. Has someone an idea?

This is my code:

```
 function modified_one_desc( $query) {
     if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
            $query->set('category_name','Blog');
            $query->set('orderby','modified');
            $query->set('order','DESC');
     }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_one_desc' );

 function modified_one_asc( $query) {
     if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
            $query->set('category_name','Blog');
            $query->set('orderby','modified');
            $query->set('order','ASC');
     }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified_one_asc' );
```

Just only one works.

Comment: Do you want to show only one newest modified post. I'm thinking of post injection here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the newest modified posts on top of the loop is via post injection using the `the_posts` filter

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, \WP_Query $q ) 
{
    // Only target the main query on the home page
    if (    $q->is_main_query()
         && $q->is_home()
         && !$q->is_paged() // Only target page one 
    ) {
        // Get the newest modified post
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category_name'  => 'blog', // Note, this must be slug
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'        => 'modified'
        ];
        $newest = get_posts( $args );

        // Make sure we have a post to inject
        if ( !$newest )
            return $posts;

        // We have a post, append it to our array of posts
       $posts = array_merge( $newest, $posts );
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You can adjust this to your needs

Comment: I never read about post injection before. Your code works perfect! (I just changed the `$args = [];` in `$args = array();`) I thank you so much! You are unbelievable!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Post injection is quite useful. It is the same exact principle that `WP_Query` uses query and inject sticky posts into the loop when stickies are not on page one ;-). My syntax is only available in PHP 5.4. If you are not still not using PHP 5.6, you should consider upgrading as all previous versions are EOL'ed